# Import one module from bitbucket git repo to github

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Github's [import tool](https://github.com/new/import) allows to transfer an entire repo from a url, I'd like to transfer only a directory/module with all related revision history from a bitbucket repo to github, is that possible?

Comment: No. A single directory does not have a history associated with it - a repository does.

Comment: Makes sense, make your comment an answer if you'd like, I'll accept it if I get no workaround suggestions. I'll wait a day or 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the entire repository and then use git on the command line to remove everything but that subfolder. Git makes this easy with `git-filter-branch`; something like:

`git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter SUBDIR`

Then force push to GitHub (you've rewritten history, so it will need to be a force push) and you're good to go.